# In Material UI how do I align right one button in a flex column?

Tags: flexbox, material-ui

New to Material UI and flex I've read a lot of documentation but for some reason I'm missing how to take a Material UI `<CancelIcon />` and align right only that icon in a `<Drawer />`. I've read that to be able to prevent the `<Drawer />` from being inline I need to use `flexDirection: 'column'`.

### Code

```js
<Drawer
  {...{
    anchor: 'right',
    open: drawerOpen,
    onClose: handleDrawerClose,
  }}
  >
  <div className={drawerContainer}>
    <CancelIcon className={cancelBtn} />
    <GetDrawerChoices />
  </div>
</Drawer>
```

### Styles

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  drawerContainer: {
    padding: '24px 0',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  cancelBtn: {
    margin: '0 28px 8px 28px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    // justify: 'flex-end',
    alignContent: 'flex-end',
  },
})

export default useStyles
```

### Research

I've tried the following:

[How to add close icon in Material UI Dialog Header top right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42363198/how-to-add-close-icon-in-material-ui-dialog-header-top-right-corner):

```js
  cancelBtn: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

[What's the right way to float right or left using the material-ui appbar with material-ui-next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686456/whats-the-right-way-to-float-right-or-left-using-the-material-ui-appbar-with-ma)

```js
cancelBtn: {
  display: 'flex',
  flex: 1,
},
```

[How to align a component to the center/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159071/how-to-align-a-component-to-the-center-right?rq=1):

```js
cancelBtn: {
  justify: 'flex-end',
},
```

Further reading: [Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container#alignment_and_flex-direction)

### Preview

[image]

In Material UI with flex how can I get the `<CancelIcon />` to align right but leave the remaining text left justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Box component outside the CancelBtn like this.

```
<Box
  display="flex"
  justifyContent="flex-end"
>
  <CancelIcon className={cancelBtn} />
</Box>
```

Or like this.

```
<Box
  display="flex"
>
  <Box flexGrow={1} />
  <CancelIcon className={cancelBtn} />
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

[hotcakedev's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65729348/1952287) answer got me where I needed. Just cleaned it up:

bring in:

```js
// Material UI
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core'
import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel'

// Styles
import useStyles from '../styles'

const { drawerContainer, cancelBtn } = useStyles()
```

the `div`:

```js
<div className={drawerContainer}>
  <Box className={cancelBtn}>
    <CancelIcon />
  </Box>
  <GetDrawerChoices />
</div>
```

and styles:

```css
drawerContainer: {
  padding: '24px 0',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
cancelBtn: {
  margin: '0 20px 8px 0',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want move only one element to right side you can use order in flex

```
cancelBtn: {
  order : 1         // it moves just cancelBtn to the right side
```

};